# Please suggest how can I extract text data from hand-filled character per box type forms using python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, image-processing, nlp

[hand-filled character per box form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YAry.jpg)

I want to automate a process in which I would get hand-filled character per box type forms in image format and I need to extract text from these forms. The boxes surrounds each letter, I have to extract all the text from the image form.

Comment: Please make an attempt, and if you still can't solve it, then ask a question. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selecting contours by size, find rotated rectangle and inverse transform make.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('4YAry.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# convert to binary image
thresh=cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV )[1]
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
for cnt in contours:
    x , y , w , h  =  cv2 . boundingRect ( cnt )
    if abs(w-345)<10: # width box is 345 px
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
srcTri=np.array( [box[1], box[0], box[2]] ).astype(np.float32)
dstTri = np.array( [[0, 0], [0, rect[1][1]], [rect[1][0],0]] ).astype(np.float32)
warp_mat = cv2.getAffineTransform(srcTri, dstTri)
warp_dst = cv2.warpAffine(img, warp_mat, (np.int0(rect[1][0]), np.int0(rect[1][1])))
N=14
s=0.99*warp_dst.shape[1]/N # tune rectangle positions
for i in range(N):
    warp_dst =  cv2.rectangle ( warp_dst , ( 2+int(i*s) ,2 ), ( 2+int((i+1)*s) , warp_dst.shape[0]-3 ), ( 255 , 255 , 255 ), 2 )

cv2.imwrite('chars.png', warp_dst)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, The black lines are getting removed, but the form that I have is having a lot of boxes. Please let me know in this code, which parameters do I need to change to get the output if the number of boxes is 30. 
I am changing this parameter, N=30, but I am not getting the results.

Comment: if abs(w-345)<10: # width box is 345 px
You need change N and 345 to actual value.

Comment: Hi, Changing N and width is not working, When I am trying with 27 boxes, the output is still coming as same as the horizontal length of previous image, can you please check Sir.